# How can I change where strongholds spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Is it possible with Bukkit to change the stronghold generation origin coordinates? The server / community I am part of is migrating to a new map, and we found coordinates where we wish to place our spawn location, but it is very far away from the center map coordinates (0, 0). This means our new spawn will not have any nearby strongholds.

Is it possible to modify the Bukkit server configuration, or utilize a world generation plugin, that will allow us to change the stronghold generation center coordinates to where our new spawn location is set?

Comment: So you just want to change where the strongholds spawn? (That by itself would be far, far simpler to do without disrupting world generation than changing where 0,0 is.)

Comment: That option is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: There might be seeds that have a location similar to your chosen spawn at (0, 0). Is your seed/map choice fixed already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two existing plugins that may do what you need.

- **[ManualGen](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/manualgen/)** allows ops to trigger a structure generation at their location with a command. Strongholds can be place manually this way by your server admin(s). The drawback is that admins who place strongholds will know where they are, which they might not want if they like to explore as a regular player too.
- **[InfiniteStrongholds](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/infinitestrongholds/)** generates strongholds across the whole world, in addition to the three vanilla strongholds. This will guarantee that there are strongholds near your spawn, though how many depends on the density value that the admins choose for the plugin. The drawback of this plugin is that Eyes of Ender currently don't detect the new strongholds, only the original three.